# Getting run-time crash log notes your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list', not sure why?

Tags: android

I am getting a run time exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'. Not sure what is wrong here.I looked at some other answers and it seemed that changing the ListView id to list was the issue but that does not seem to be working.

activity_search.xml

```
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  Single List Item Design -->
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:textSize="16dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>
```

SearchActivity.java

```
package com.chance.squat;

import com.chance.squat.R;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SearchActivity extends ListActivity {

    // url to make request
    private static String url = "http://192.168.1.115:3000/bathrooms/nearby.json/?lat=45.580639&lon=-122.677682";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_BATHROOMS = "bathrooms";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "ID";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_DISTANCE = "distance";

    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray bathrooms = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> bathroomList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Creating JSON Parser instance
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        try {
            // Getting Array of Contacts
            bathrooms = json.getJSONArray(TAG_BATHROOMS);

            // looping through All Contacts
            for(int i = 0; i < bathrooms.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = bathrooms.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String distance = c.getString(TAG_DISTANCE);
                String distanceTrimmed = distance.substring(0,4) + " " + "miles away";

                System.out.println(name);

                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                map.put(TAG_DISTANCE, distanceTrimmed);

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                bathroomList.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, bathroomList,
                R.layout.list_item,
                new String[] { TAG_NAME}, new int[] {
                         R.id.name });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // selecting single ListView item
        ListView lv = getListView();

        // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                //String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
                //String distance = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.distance)).getText().toString();


                // Starting new intent
                //Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SeachActivity.class);
                //in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
                //in.putExtra(TAG_DISTANCE, distance);
                //startActivity(in);

            }
        });


    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change ListView id to `android:id="@android:id/list"` because when you are extending `ListActivity` you must have ListView id android.R.id.list

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</ListView>
```

Comment: That got rid of that problem but I'm still getting 01-19 10:16:52.683: E/AndroidRuntime(588): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.chance.squat/com.chance.squat.SearchActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
Any ideas on that one? It is declared in the manifest.

Comment: I didn't have permsission to use internet in manifest file. Thanks for the help.